# Recognize what is on image

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision, neural-network

i'm doing a little project with neural networks. I've read about digit recognition, with MNIST dataset and thought if it possible to make same dataset but with regular objects we see every day.
So here's algorithm( if we can say so):
All is done with opencv library for python
1) Get contours from image. This is not literally contours, but something that looks so.
I've done this with this code:

```
def findContour(self):
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(self.image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    gray = cv2.bilateralFilter(gray, 11, 17, 17)
    self.image = cv2.Canny(gray, 30, 200)
```

2) Next need to create training set.
I copy and edit this message. Change rotation and flip it -- now we have about 40 images, which are consists of rotated contours.
3) Now i'm gonna dump this images to a csv file.
These images are represented as 3D array, so i flatten them using .flatten function from numpy. Next this flatten vector is written in csv file, with label as last character

This is what i've done, and want to ask : will it work out?
Next i want to use everything except last element as input x vector, and last elements as y vector. (like [here](http://www.pyimagesearch.com/2014/09/22/getting-started-deep-learning-python/))

Recognizing will be done same way : we getting contour of image, and feed it to neural network, output will be label.

Is it even possible, or better not to try?

Comment: _will it work out?_ No. Really, you're wasting your time. Read instead about Object Recognition, and the latest papers on the subject. You'll learn that it's more difficult (and interesting) than just extracting contours...

Comment: I disagree; don't read current papers, that's far more confusing than other methods.  Google "Object Recognition neural network Tutorial", or something along those lines and you'll find many tutorials you can look at!

Comment: @Christopher probably I should rephrase it in: "start simple, look at online tutorials, then when you want to do something more meaningful than a toy problem look at new papers and state of the art approaches". ;D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is plenty of room for experimentation.  However, you should not reinvent the wheel, except as a learning exercise.  Research the paradigm, learn what already exists, and then go make your own wheel improvements.

I strongly recommend that you start with image recognition in CNNs (convolutional neural networks).  A lot of wonderful work has been done with the ILSVRC 2012 image data set (a.k.a. ImageNet files).  In fact, a large part of today's NN popularity comes from Alex Krizhevsky's breakthrough (resulting in AlexNet, the first NN to win the ILSVRC) and ensuing topologies (ResNet, GoogleNet, VGG, etc.).

The simple answer is to let your network "decide" what's important in the original photo.  Certainly, flatten the image and feed it contours, but don't be surprised if a training run on the original images produces superior results.

Search for resources on "Image Recognition introduction" and pick a few of the hits that match your current reading and topic interests.  There are plenty of good ones out there.

When you get to programming your own models, I strongly recommend that you use an existing framework, rather than building all that collateral from scratch.  Dump the CSV format; there are better ones with pre-packaged I/O routines and plenty of support.  The idea is to let you design your network, rather than manipulating data all the time.

Popular frameworks include Caffe, TensorFlow, Torch, Theano, and CNTK, among others.  So far, I've found Caffe and Torch to have the easiest overall learning curves, although there's not so much difference that I'd actually *recommend* one over another in general.  Look for one that has good documentation and examples in your areas of interest.